# How to properly target Linux as Target OS in VisualStudio 2022?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am developing a .NET6.0 console app in VisualStudio 2022. The app will run on Linux.

In project Properties/Application/General, there is a "Target OS" setting. The drop down list allows me to choose from the following OS':

[image]

There is no Linux option, so I set this to (None) and when publish the app with "Target runtime" in "Publish profile" as 'linux-x64':

[image]

...it will run on Linux no problem.

But since there is no Linux option in the drop down menu in application settings, hence my questions:

1. Is this the case for everyone, or am I lacking something in my VS installation?
2. Does this setting affect the builds at all - since (None) doesn't seem to have any effect and the settings in publish profile seem to have the last word anyway.
3. Is (None) setting fine if I want to publish for Linux, or will there be any ramifications?

Comment: Very clumsy right now, but do note that it follows the specification for the OS-specific target framework monikers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks, scroll down to ".NET 5+ OS-specific TFMs".  Nothing listed for linux flavors there either.  So "None" is the correct choice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`None` is correct for the `Target OS` since it has nothing extra. All of the other target frameworks contain platform-specific features. (Like `WPF` related Namespaces are under `Windows`). Another way to look at it is `None=Everywhere`

What you might be interested in is setting the `RuntimeIdentifier` or `RuntimeIdentifiers` in your `.csproj`.

For your case the following is probably what you'll want:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

With this set, the compiler/Visual Studio will warn you about the usage of methods not available on one of the specified platforms. `Console` has some that only work on Windows.

[More about RIDs here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog)

Comment: Great, this also means that to target Linux arm64 the RuntimeIdentifier in .csproj needs to be set since this option is not available from Publish profile's target settings drop down menu. Additionally it sometimes even has to exactly match the distribution according to this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/src/runtime.json